# Schedule Javascript Server Side Script Execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-hosting, serverside-javascript

- Is it possible to run javascript server side?
- Is it possible to access a script http://mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/performDailyIndex.js. And it will schedule a script to run every four hours? Will a webhost allow myself to do this or is this bad webmaster practices?

The idea is to trigger my webcrawler/indexer for my website - a specialised search engine - to run & index a set of web seeds.

Maybe I can configure through cpanel a way to automatically run my script at a certain time?

Comment: *Is it possible to run javascript server side?* Yes. *Maybe I can configure through cpanel a way to automatically run my script at a certain time?* Yeah, maybe, how can we know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Javascript on server side you can use :

- Node.JS : http://nodejs.org/
- Rhino : http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

Up to you to find a provider with a scheduler. I take an example, Heroku, it provide a scheduler addon :

- http://addons.heroku.com/scheduler

ps: Heroku can host NodeJS.

Hope it help.

Comment: Instead of Heroku, a simple good ol' CRON-job may be enough. You could also consider using PM2 to keep a NodeJS service up and handle the scheduling from within your NodeJS service which I would personally prefer because it's easier to handle situations e.g. when a previous cycle hasn't finished yet and prevent things from getting messy...